# Integrating the product of lines.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, definite-integrals, closed-form, products

## The Question.

> Suppose we have $n$ linear functions $f_k$ defined on $[x_1,x_2]$. Let $f_k(x_1)=y_k$ and $f_k(x_2)=z_k$ denote the function values at the endpoints of the interval. We would like to calculate
>
> $$\mathfrak{P}(n)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \prod_{k=1}^n f_k(x) \, dx$$
>
> in terms of $x_1,x_2,$ and $y_k, z_k$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

The motivation for this comes from mathematical programming-- specifically, an algorithm I'm writing that requires integrating the product of a large number of piecewise linear functions. What I would like is to find a closed form for $\mathfrak{P}(n)$.

Let's work through a few examples and see if a formula jumps out at us.

### Example: $n=2$

The first thing to do is write the $f_k$ in terms of the endpoint values. Solving $f_k(x_1)=mx_1+b=y_k$ and $f_k(x_2)=mx_2+b=z_k$, we get

$$f_k(x)=\frac{z_k-y_k}{x_2-x_1}x+\frac{y_k x_2-z_kx_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

So, then, we are calculating

$$
\mathfrak{P}(2)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \left(\frac{z_1-y_1}{x_2-x_1}x+\frac{y_1 x_2-z_1x_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)\left(\frac{z_2-y_2}{x_2-x_1}x+\frac{y_2 x_2-z_2x_1}{x_2-x_1}\right) \, dx
$$

which, God help us, is

$$
\left.\frac{x \left(3 x (y_1 z_2 (x_1+x_2)+y_2 z_1 (x_1+x_2)-2 x_1 z_1 z_2-2 x_2 y_1 y_2)+6 (x_1 z_1-x_2 y_1) (x_1 z_2-x_2 y_2)+2 x^2 (y_1-z_1) (y_2-z_2)\right)}{6 (x_1-x_2){}^2}\right|_{x_1}^{x_2}
$$
Luckily, this simplifies quite a bit down to
$$
\frac{1}{6} (x_2-x_1)(y_1 (2 y_2+z_2)+z_1 (y_2+2 z_2)).
$$

Alright! It didn't turn out that bad.

### Example: $n=3,\ldots, 6$

Let's take a look at some other values of $\mathfrak{P}$. I'll spare you the intermediate calculations.

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathfrak{P}(3)&=&\frac{1}{12} (x_2-x_1) (y_1 y_3 (3 y_2+z_2)+y_1 z_3 (y_2+z_2)+y_3 z_1 (y_2+z_2)+z_1 z_3 (y_2+3 z_2))\\
\mathfrak{P}(4)&=&\frac{1}{60} (x_2-x_1) (y_1 y_4 (3 y_2 (4 y_3+z_3)+z_2 (3 y_3+2 z_3))+y_1 z_4 (3 y_2 y_3+2 y_2 z_3+2 y_3 z_2+3 z_2 z_3)+y_4 z_1 (3 y_2 y_3+2 y_2 z_3+2 y_3 z_2+3 z_2 z_3)+z_1 z_4 (y_2 (2 y_3+3 z_3)+3 z_2 (y_3+4 z_3)))\\
\mathfrak{P}(5)&=&\frac{1}{60}(x_2-x_1) (y_1 y_5 (2 y_2 y_4 (5 y_3+z_3)+y_2 z_4 (2 y_3+z_3)+y_4 z_2 (2 y_3+z_3)+z_2 z_4 (y_3+z_3))+y_1 z_5 (y_2 y_4 (2 y_3+z_3)+y_2 z_4 (y_3+z_3)+y_4 z_2 (y_3+z_3)+z_2 z_4 (y_3+2 z_3))+y_5 z_1 (y_2 y_4 (2 y_3+z_3)+y_2 z_4 (y_3+z_3)+y_4 z_2 (y_3+z_3)+z_2 z_4 (y_3+2 z_3))+z_1 z_5 (y_2 y_4 (y_3+z_3)+y_2 z_4 (y_3+2 z_3)+y_4 z_2 (y_3+2 z_3)+2 z_2 z_4 (y_3+5 z_3)))\\
\mathfrak{P}(6)&=&\frac{1}{420} (x_2-x_1) (y_1 y_2 (2 y_3 y_6 (5 y_4 (6 y_5+z_5)+z_4 (5 y_5+2 z_5))+y_3 z_6 (10 y_4 y_5+4 y_4 z_5+4 y_5 z_4+3 z_4 z_5)+y_6 z_3 (10 y_4 y_5+4 y_4 z_5+4 y_5 z_4+3 z_4 z_5)+z_3 z_6 (4 y_4 y_5+3 y_4 z_5+3 y_5 z_4+4 z_4 z_5))+y_1 z_2 (y_3 y_6 (10 y_4 y_5+4 y_4 z_5+4 y_5 z_4+3 z_4 z_5)+y_3 z_6 (4 y_4 y_5+3 y_4 z_5+3 y_5 z_4+4 z_4 z_5)+y_6 z_3 (4 y_4 y_5+3 y_4 z_5+3 y_5 z_4+4 z_4 z_5)+z_3 z_6 (3 y_4 y_5+4 y_4 z_5+4 y_5 z_4+10 z_4 z_5))+y_2 z_1 (y_3 y_6 (10 y_4 y_5+4 y_4 z_5+4 y_5 z_4+3 z_4 z_5)+y_3 z_6 (4 y_4 y_5+3 y_4 z_5+3 y_5 z_4+4 z_4 z_5)+y_6 z_3 (4 y_4 y_5+3 y_4 z_5+3 y_5 z_4+4 z_4 z_5)+z_3 z_6 (3 y_4 y_5+4 y_4 z_5+4 y_5 z_4+10 z_4 z_5))+z_1 z_2 (y_3 y_6 (4 y_4 y_5+3 y_4 z_5+3 y_5 z_4+4 z_4 z_5)+y_3 z_6 (3 y_4 y_5+4 y_4 z_5+4 y_5 z_4+10 z_4 z_5)+y_6 z_3 (3 y_4 y_5+4 y_4 z_5+4 y_5 z_4+10 z_4 z_5)+2 z_3 z_6 (y_4 (2 y_5+5 z_5)+5 z_4 (y_5+6 z_5))))\end{eqnarray*}$$

There certainly seems to be some pattern here.

The coefficient has a denominator of $\operatorname{lcm}\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ and we're always multiplying by $x_2-x_1$, so let's just get rid of that first term by looking at $\frac{\operatorname{lcm}\{1,\ldots,n+1\}}{x_2-x_1}\mathfrak{P}_n$. Maybe it will help us see the pattern if we expand everything out.

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{\operatorname{lcm}\{1,\ldots,4\}}{x_2-x_1}\mathfrak{P}_3&=&3 y_1 y_2 y_3+y_1 y_2 z_3+y_1 y_3 z_2+y_1 z_2 z_3+y_2 y_3 z_1+y_2 z_1 z_3+y_3 z_1 z_2+3 z_1 z_2 z_3\\
\frac{\operatorname{lcm}\{1,\ldots,5\}}{x_2-x_1}\mathfrak{P}_4&=&12 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4+3 y_1 y_2 y_3 z_4+3 y_1 y_2 y_4 z_3+2 y_1 y_2 z_3 z_4+3 y_1 y_3 y_4 z_2+2 y_1 y_3 z_2 z_4+2 y_1 y_4 z_2 z_3+\cdots\\
&\cdots&3 y_1 z_2 z_3 z_4+3 y_2 y_3 y_4 z_1+2 y_2 y_3 z_1 z_4+2 y_2 y_4 z_1 z_3+3 y_2 z_1 z_3 z_4+2 y_3 y_4 z_1 z_2+3 y_3 z_1 z_2 z_4+\cdots\\&\cdots&3 y_4 z_1 z_2 z_3+12 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4\\
\frac{\operatorname{lcm}\{1,\ldots,6\}}{x_2-x_1}\mathfrak{P}_5&=&10 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5+2 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 z_5+2 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_5 z_4+y_1 y_2 y_3 z_4 z_5+2 y_1 y_2 y_4 y_5 z_3+y_1 y_2 y_4 z_3 z_5+\cdots\\&\cdots&y_1 y_2 y_5 z_3 z_4+y_1 y_2 z_3 z_4 z_5+2 y_1 y_3 y_4 y_5 z_2+y_1 y_3 y_4 z_2 z_5+y_1 y_3 y_5 z_2 z_4+y_1 y_3 z_2 z_4 z_5+\cdots\\&\cdots&y_1 y_4 y_5 z_2 z_3+y_1 y_4 z_2 z_3 z_5+y_1 y_5 z_2 z_3 z_4+2 y_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5+2 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5 z_1+y_2 y_3 y_4 z_1 z_5+\cdots\\&\cdots&y_2 y_3 y_5 z_1 z_4+y_2 y_3 z_1 z_4 z_5+y_2 y_4 y_5 z_1 z_3+y_2 y_4 z_1 z_3 z_5+y_2 y_5 z_1 z_3 z_4+2 y_2 z_1 z_3 z_4 z_5+\cdots\\&\cdots&y_3 y_4 y_5 z_1 z_2+y_3 y_4 z_1 z_2 z_5+y_3 y_5 z_1 z_2 z_4+2 y_3 z_1 z_2 z_4 z_5+y_4 y_5 z_1 z_2 z_3+2 y_4 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_5+\cdots\\&\cdots&2 y_5 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4+10 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5\\
\frac{\operatorname{lcm}\{1,\ldots,7\}}{x_2-x_1}\mathfrak{P}_6&=&
60 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5 y_6+10 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5 z_6+10 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_6 z_5+4 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 z_5 z_6+10 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_5 y_6 z_4+\cdots\\&\cdots&
4 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_5 z_4 z_6+4 y_1 y_2 y_3 y_6 z_4 z_5+3 y_1 y_2 y_3 z_4 z_5 z_6+10 y_1 y_2 y_4 y_5 y_6 z_3+4 y_1 y_2 y_4 y_5 z_3 z_6+\cdots\\&\cdots&
4 y_1 y_2 y_4 y_6 z_3 z_5+3 y_1 y_2 y_4 z_3 z_5 z_6+4 y_1 y_2 y_5 y_6 z_3 z_4+3 y_1 y_2 y_5 z_3 z_4 z_6+3 y_1 y_2 y_6 z_3 z_4 z_5+\cdots\\&\cdots&
4 y_1 y_2 z_3 z_4 z_5 z_6+10 y_1 y_3 y_4 y_5 y_6 z_2+4 y_1 y_3 y_4 y_5 z_2 z_6+4 y_1 y_3 y_4 y_6 z_2 z_5+3 y_1 y_3 y_4 z_2 z_5 z_6+\cdots\\&\cdots&
4 y_1 y_3 y_5 y_6 z_2 z_4+3 y_1 y_3 y_5 z_2 z_4 z_6+3 y_1 y_3 y_6 z_2 z_4 z_5+4 y_1 y_3 z_2 z_4 z_5 z_6+4 y_1 y_4 y_5 y_6 z_2 z_3+\cdots\\&\cdots&
3 y_1 y_4 y_5 z_2 z_3 z_6+3 y_1 y_4 y_6 z_2 z_3 z_5+4 y_1 y_4 z_2 z_3 z_5 z_6+3 y_1 y_5 y_6 z_2 z_3 z_4+4 y_1 y_5 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_6+\cdots\\&\cdots&
4 y_1 y_6 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5+10 y_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5 z_6+10 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5 y_6 z_1+4 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5 z_1 z_6+4 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_6 z_1 z_5+\cdots\\&\cdots&
3 y_2 y_3 y_4 z_1 z_5 z_6+4 y_2 y_3 y_5 y_6 z_1 z_4+3 y_2 y_3 y_5 z_1 z_4 z_6+3 y_2 y_3 y_6 z_1 z_4 z_5+4 y_2 y_3 z_1 z_4 z_5 z_6+\cdots\\&\cdots&
4 y_2 y_4 y_5 y_6 z_1 z_3+3 y_2 y_4 y_5 z_1 z_3 z_6+3 y_2 y_4 y_6 z_1 z_3 z_5+4 y_2 y_4 z_1 z_3 z_5 z_6+3 y_2 y_5 y_6 z_1 z_3 z_4+\cdots\\&\cdots&
4 y_2 y_5 z_1 z_3 z_4 z_6+4 y_2 y_6 z_1 z_3 z_4 z_5+10 y_2 z_1 z_3 z_4 z_5 z_6+4 y_3 y_4 y_5 y_6 z_1 z_2+3 y_3 y_4 y_5 z_1 z_2 z_6+\cdots\\&\cdots&
3 y_3 y_4 y_6 z_1 z_2 z_5+4 y_3 y_4 z_1 z_2 z_5 z_6+3 y_3 y_5 y_6 z_1 z_2 z_4+4 y_3 y_5 z_1 z_2 z_4 z_6+4 y_3 y_6 z_1 z_2 z_4 z_5+\cdots\\&\cdots&
10 y_3 z_1 z_2 z_4 z_5 z_6+3 y_4 y_5 y_6 z_1 z_2 z_3+4 y_4 y_5 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_6+4 y_4 y_6 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_5+10 y_4 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_5 z_6+\cdots\\&\cdots&
4 y_5 y_6 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4+10 y_5 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_6+10 y_6 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5+60 z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5 z_6
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

The pattern in the variables is easy to see-- there are $2^n$ terms, each of which has terms $1$ through $n$ of either the $y$ or the $z$. (What I mean is, the terms are in 1-to-1 correspondence with $\{y_1,z_1\}\times \cdots \times \{y_n,z_n\}$.)

But, what are the coefficients?

Comment: Do you specifically want a formula for each coefficient, or will any efficient algorithm to compute $\mathfrak{P}(n)$ suffice?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I was looking for the former but I'd take the latter. (Always the possibility it could turn into the former, too.)

Comment: This probably doesn't help, but if you can do substitution (since any efficient algorithm is enough), this might be equivalent to calculating $\int_0^1 \prod(m_ix+c_i) dx$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By translating and rescaling you can write 
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{P}(n) 
&= (x_2 - x_1) \int_0^1 \prod_{k=1}^n (y_k(1 - x) + z_kx)\,dx \\
&= (x_2 - x_1) \int_0^1 \sum_{S \subset [n]}\left((1 - x)^{|S|}x^{n-|S|} \prod_{k \in S} y_k \prod_{k \not \in S} z_k\right)\,dx \\
&= (x_2 - x_1) \sum_{S \subset [n]} B\big(n-|S|+1\,,\, |S|+1 \big) \prod_{k \in S} y_k \prod_{k \not \in S} z_k \\
&= (x_2 - x_1) \sum_{S \subset [n]} \frac{1}{(n+1) \binom{n}{|S|}} \prod_{k \in S} y_k \prod_{k \not \in S} z_k 
\end{align*}
where $[n] = \{1, \dots, n\}$ and $B(a, b) = \int_0^1 x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \,dx = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$ is the Beta function.

---

**Addendum:** If you need a quick way to calculate this, note that this is 
$$(x_2 - x_1) \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{a_j}{(n+1)\binom{n}{j}}$$
where $a_j$ is the coefficient of $x^j$ in the polynomial $\prod_{k=1}^n (xy_k + z_k)$.